# How to format from 7 to 2 decimal places

Tags: r

I am exploring the tidyverse package.

I am okay with the below code:

```
library(dslabs)
data("murders")

murders <- mutate(murders, rate = total / population * 100000)
murders

filter(murders, rate <= 0.71)
```

The pipe - Using the pipe the code is as below:

```
murders %>% select(state, region, rate) %>% filter(rate <= 0.71)
```

How can I format the rate from the current 7 decimal places to 2?

Comment: Do you want to the printed result to have 2 decimal places, but the data to retain its precision or do you want to round the data to 2 decimal places?

Comment: Question was indented on the printed result to have 2 decimal places, but the data to retain its precision, however you may also address address the rounding of the data to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

I presume that your desire is to just print these data with two decimal places and not to actually round them? If you do wish to round the data, that is simple:

**Rounding**

```
library(dplyr)
library(dslabs)
data("murders")

murders %>% 
  select(state, region, rate) %>% 
  filter(rate <= 0.71) %>% 
  mutate(rate = round(rate, 2))

          state        region rate
1        Hawaii          West 0.51
2          Iowa North Central 0.69
3 New Hampshire     Northeast 0.38
4  North Dakota North Central 0.59
5       Vermont     Northeast 0.32
```

**tibble workaround**

If you do not wish to round the data, but you wish to only print two digits, you can do this by converting your data to a `tibble` and setting the `pillar.sigfig` option. Note that `options(pillar.sigfig = 2)` prints two significant digits, not decimal places explicitly. So if your data had a value of `1.23345` it would print `1.2`. However, your rates are all less than one, so this should function as a workaround. You can control decimal places precisely using the `vctrs` package, and that approach is below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(dslabs)
data("murders")
options(pillar.sigfig = 2)

murders2 <- murders %>% 
  select(state, region, rate) %>% 
  filter(rate <= 0.71) %>% 
  tibble()
murders2

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  state         region         rate
  <chr>         <fct>         <dbl>
1 Hawaii        West           0.51
2 Iowa          North Central  0.69
3 New Hampshire Northeast      0.38
4 North Dakota  North Central  0.59
5 Vermont       Northeast      0.32
```

An important distinction about the second approach is that the underlying values are not changed. If you grab just on value from the `tibble`, you get the full number of digits back:

```
murders2$rate[3]
[1] 0.3798036
```

Setting `options(pillar.sigfig = )` changes a global option for the printing of all `tibbles`. To resume normal behavior, set `options(pillar.sigfig = NULL)`.

Note, setting a similar option for decimal places and not significant figures has been a feature request for the `tibble` package (https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/772), but seems unlikely to be implemented at this time.

**A better solution using vctrs**

There is hope if your data is more complex! The `vctrs` package allows you do define new vector classes with various behaviors (including printing a certain number of decimal places). In fact, setting decimal places is one of the two use case examples in `vignette("s3-vector")`. Run the code from the vignette (reproduced below) to create the new class, then `mutate` your column.

```
library(vctrs)
new_decimal <- function(x = double(), digits = 2L) {
  vec_assert(x, ptype = double())
  vec_assert(digits, ptype = integer(), size = 1)

  new_vctr(x, digits = digits, class = "vctrs_decimal")
}

decimal <- function(x = double(), digits = 2L) {
  x <- vec_cast(x, double())
  digits <- vec_recycle(vec_cast(digits, integer()), 1L)

  new_decimal(x, digits = digits)
}

digits <- function(x) attr(x, "digits")

format.vctrs_decimal <- function(x, ...) {
  sprintf(paste0("%-0.", digits(x), "f"), x)
}

vec_ptype_abbr.vctrs_decimal <- function(x, ...) {
  "dec"
}

murders3 <- murders %>% 
  select(state, region, rate) %>% 
  filter(rate <= 0.71) %>% 
  mutate(rate = decimal(rate, 2))
murders3

          state        region rate
1        Hawaii          West 0.51
2          Iowa North Central 0.69
3 New Hampshire     Northeast 0.38
4  North Dakota North Central 0.59
5       Vermont     Northeast 0.32
```

This benefit of this `vctrs` approach is that it handles any value and can be done without converting to a `tibble` if you do not want to.

```
decimal(1.2345, 2)

<vctrs_decimal[1]>
[1] 1.23
```

Again, the full value is preserved, though you need to remove the class or change the `digits` attribute to see more decimal places:

```
unclass(num) 
  
[1] 1.2345
attr(,"digits")
[1] 2

attributes(num)$digits <- 4
num

<vctrs_decimal[1]>
[1] 1.2345
```